# Problema con archivo Host de windows

Tags: windows, dns, host

Desarrollé un sitio web con MEAN Stack y lo quiero poner en una pc local con windows 10 haciendo función de server. Modifiqué el archivo host y puse el IP de la pc server espacio y el nombre que quiero q tenga mi sitio. De manera local funciona bien pero al crear una wifi con la pc para acceder desde otro dispositivo no funciona. Si funciona accediendo desde otro dispositivo mediante el IP/ sitio pero nombre del sitio/sitio no funciona. Tambien tengo dicho en la configuración de la wifi que el servidor DNS va a ser la pc donde modifiqué el archivo host para que resuelva las peticiones. Es como si windows "no server" no tuviesr la funcionalidad de servidor DNS. Como podría solucionar esto sin tener que instalar un Windows server?

Comment: Si vas por la vía de editar archivos hosts, lo vas a tener que hacer en cada PC desde donde quieras entrar. Sino podes usar DNSMasq en tu router y hacerlo desde ahí.

Comment: Ok. Pero no existe algún programa gratuito para windows que haga la función de servidor DNS?